# Ternary operator in while loop condition

Tags: python

I have encountered a weird bug with the ternary operator that I cannot understand the reasoning for. The problem is that there is a buffer from which messages need to be sent when there are more than X with Y measurements packed into one message, or after some time the buffer needs to be cleared and all remaining measurements need to be sent.

The code I used to try and accomplish this basically was the following:

```
while len(buffer) > 0 if send_all else Y - 1:
  for measurement in buffer[:Y]:
    send_buffer.append(measurement)

  del buffer[:Y]
  send(send_buffer)
```

The problem was that this caused an infinite loop if `send_all` was False.

I fixed this problem by removing the ternary operator and having it stored in a variable instead:

```
if send_all:
  send_until = 0
else:
  send_until = Y - 1

while len(buffer) > send_until:
  for measurement in buffer[:Y]:
    send_buffer.append(measurement)

  del buffer[:Y]
  send(send_buffer)
```

But I cannot understand why this would solve the problem as the two code excerpts should be, as far as I can see, equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the ternary operator binds very loosely.  This:

```
while len(buffer) > 0 if send_all else Y - 1:
```

is parsed as this:

```
while (len(buffer) > 0) if send_all else Y - 1:
```

and `Y-1` is probably nonzero.  You need parentheses:

```
while len(buffer) > (0 if send_all else Y - 1):
```